# multi-boot Win and Ubuntu - reserve primary or 2ndary partition?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I just got a Lenovo T420s with 500GB HDD, to replace my old T61 with Ubuntu 16.04. I have already installed XP on the first primary partition. As I learned in the forum, Windows partitions should precede Ubuntu. So I would like to reserve two partitions for Win7 and 10, which I don't yet have, but don't want to delay my Ubuntu installation.

My question is: should I create two primary partitions for Win7 and Win10 and install Ubuntu on the extended partition or should I just leave two logical drives in the extended partition for them?

thanks much.

Comment: You should create  primary partitions for Win7 and Win10. Keep in mind that installing Windows at a later date will nuke GRUB, and you'll have to use a live USB to reinstall GRUB.

Comment: If on primary partitions, and you move boot flag to partition you are installing into, then you can boot directly from grub. Otherwise each Windows install will overwrite previous bootloader in the one NTFS partition with boot flag. Last install  will update BCD will all Windows but then that is the only Windows grub finds to boot. Why XP, not really safe to use anymore. And make sure in Windows 10 that fast start up is off. That will even conflict with multiple Windows boot. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions

Answer (score 2):

### The installation of Windows should precede the installation of Ubuntu *in time*

The order in the partition table or position on the disk makes no difference except that Windows wants primary partitions as already explained by Android Dev.

Ubuntu can be installed in a logical root partition an a logical swap partition inside an extended partition. These partitions can be created at any time (also after installing Windows).

Finally: Windows XP needs an MSDOS partition table, which means max 4 primary partitions or 3 primary partitions and one extended partition (with several logical partitions inside). And remember that XP no longer receives any security updates, so please avoid connecting it to the internet.